# Cordova geolocation plugin VS. HTML5 geolocation API

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation

I was using just html5, but recently I switched to Phonegap/Cordova.
Regarding geolocation I used html5 API with:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
```

which worked enough well for my needs.
Now (with Cordova) I have another tool available, the Cordova Geolocation plugin.
What do you think is the best choice?